# c# imagetools gif to png

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml

I try to convert .gif to .png using ImageTools. Unfortunately I have a failure and I don't know why. It's my code - simple, but it's not working. Could you say where is a mistake? Thanks a lot.

```
fs = new FileStream(@"\Photo.gif", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
PngEncoder encoder = new PngEncoder();
ExtendedImage ei = new ExtendedImage();
ei.SetSource(fs);
MemoryStream toms = new MemoryStream();
encoder.Encode(ei, toms);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.StreamSource = toms;
image1.Source = bi;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: after ei.SetSource(fs); ei still empty... and image1.Source is empty too. And it is good if I have file in the local storage, but if I load file from web I will convert it in the .png and save it to the disk. But ei.SetSource(fs); doesnt implement and encoder.Encode(ei, toms); doesnt implement too.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twss4wb0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
// Load the image.
System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\test.bmp");

// Save the image in JPEG format.
image1.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// Save the image in GIF format.
image1.Save(@"C:\test.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

// Save the image in PNG format.
image1.Save(@"C:\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: i like this, its simple and uses pre-existing functionality.

Comment: System.Drawing is not supported in WP7.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code for converting bitmap image to PNG format.

```
    private byte[] ConvertToPNG(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        // Save to memory using the Png format
        bmp.Save (ms, ImageFormat.Png);

        // read to end
        byte[] bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
        bmp.Dispose();
        ms.Close();

        return bmpBytes;
    }
```

If you want to change the Format then you can also change it by ImageFormat.Jpeg, ImageFormat.gif, etc.